# Populate Drop Down List Box (DDLB) with two values in PowerBuilder

Tags: string, drop-down-menu, powerbuilder

I've created a Drop Down List Box (DDLB) in my window (I'm using PowerBuilder 10.5). Once I would call my function, the DDLB would fill with all the different cities from my table. This is the code I've used:

```
FOR li_i=1 TO ii_br_red
ls_city = dw_city.GetItemString(li_i, 'city')
IF ddlb_city.FindItem(ls_city, 1) = -1 THEN 
ddlb_city.AddItem(ls_city) END IF; NEXT
```

Next part of the code is in the ddlb "selectionchanged" event...

```
 dw_city.SetFilter("city = '" + this.text + "'")
 dw_city.Filter()
```

This works great, and after calling my function (via click on a command button) I'd get a list of all different cities in my table, ex.

```
Paris
London
New York
Washington
```

No town would be listed twice.
What I need to do now is add a country next to every city in my DDLB. So that after clicking my command button I would get this in my DDLB:

```
Paris (France)
London (GB)
New York (USA)
Washington (USA)
```

Any advice? Thanks in advance...

SECOND QUESTION, similar to this subject: I have an SQL code:

```
SELECT distinct name FROM table1;
```

This gives me 8 different names. What I want to do is fill another DDLB, ddlb_1 with these names, but this must occur on the open event of my program. This is what I've written in the open event of my program:

```
string ls_name
SELECT distinct name INTO :ls_name FROM tabel1;
ddlb_1.AddItem(ls_name)
```

But this only gives me the first name. I'm guessing I need some kind of count, but I just can't pull it off.

Comment: Just to add a comment, while I personally believe this would be easier with a Drop Down Data Window, I am obliged to use a Drop Down List Box. :)

Comment: Do you have the country in the same DW as the cities? Do you have another table with it? It would be better to look for the country of a city right after the `GetItemString` to fill at the same time in the ddlb

Comment: Your code sample isn't complete, and I doubt it "works great" as is: I guess that there is a missing `NEXT` just after the `END IF` and also that you call the `setfilter` from another piece of code

Comment: Correct, I do have "Next" at the end, and my setfilter  is called from another event (ddlb selectionchanged event). Sorry for not specifying that out. The Countries are in the same DW as cities, yes.

Comment: How would I look for the country right after my getitemstring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to change the design of the program, and as you states that the country is in the same DW, you could hack the code a little to add the country to the ddlb (I suppose that the country is available on the same row of the dw):

```
String ls_country
FOR li_i=1 TO ii_br_red
    ls_city = dw_city.GetItemString(li_i, 'city')
    IF ddlb_city.FindItem(ls_city, 1) = -1 THEN 
        ls_country = dw_city.GetItemString(li_i, 'country')
        ddlb_city.AddItem(ls_city + ' (' + ls_country + ')')
    END IF
NEXT
```

A quick and dirty hack to get back the value in the event to filter the DW would be

```
int p
string ls_city

ls_city = this.text
p = pos(ls_city, '(')
if p > 0 then ls_city = left(ls_city, p - 2) //skip the "space + (country)" part
dw_city.SetFilter("city = '" + ls_city + "'")
dw_city.Filter()
```

**But this kind of code is difficult to maintain and should be replaced by something else, as the processing of the city value is strongly coupled to its representation in the list.**

A better solution would be a dropdowndatawindow, or (worse) an array of the cities names where the index of a city + country in the ddlb would correspond to the index of the bare city name suitable for filtering the DW

Comment: At the moment I'm having hardware problems, as soon I get them fix I will try this and report back!!

Comment: Hi. The code above gives me what I want, populates my ddlb with cities and countries, but now my filter doesn't work - once I click on a value in ddlb (ex. Paris(France)), I get nothing in my window. I assume I need to change the "setfilter" code, but I can't seem to make it work? Any advice?

Comment: @JohnBlue: sorry I answered only on the text presentation part. As you reuse this string to filter the DW it needs obviuosly to remove the parens part. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should modify the "source" datawindow' select, and you should get the final result which you want, and you would only need to copy the datas from the datawindow to the ddlb. You should use distinct in the select something like this:

```
select distinct city + ' (' + country_code + ')' from cities_and_countries_table
```

of course you should replace the "city", "country_code" to the actual column name in your table as well the table-name. With this you will get every city only once and they will be already concatenated with the country code.

Br. Gábor

Comment: Hmm, I'd like to avoid touching into the source select as it is quite big... What I want to say is that the project is now on it's way, and tampering there would put me back.

Answer (score 0):

Does it really have to be DDLB? I would give the user a Single Line Edit for the city name and filter the DW as the user types.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does. I used a single line edit as a filter for the price, but for the city/state combo the user wants a ddlb.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own second question, this is how I've done it finally...

```
String ls_name
DECLARE xy CURSOR FOR
SELECT distinct name FROM table1;
OPEN xy;
FETCH xy INTO :ls_name;
do until sqlca.sqlcode <> 0
ddlb_1.AddItem(ls_name);
FETCH xyINTO :ls_name;
loop
CLOSE xy;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to PowerBuilder, But I just used that kind of scenario, however I used a DDW (Drop Down Data Window) Instead of a List Box On this case, you can display more than one column as soon as the DW gets the focus and you'd be able to dynamically populate the data. Give it a try. It worked for me, DW's are a pain in the neck when you're just starting (as in my case) but you can do a lot with it

Comment: The OP mentioned in a comment that they are obliged to use a DDLB and not a DDW.